# Running commands in rust (vim)

Tags: vim, rust, command

```
std::process::Command::new("/usr/bin/sh")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("vim")
    .arg("file")
    .spawn()
    .expect("Error: Failed to run editor");
```

When I run this code, a vim process is ran, editing the file, although it is not opened up in the terminal (not sure the exact terminology) how could I/is it possible to actually have vim open in the terminal

Comment: Minor nitpick: sh is usually `/bin/sh`, not `/usr/bin/sh`. BTW is it really necessary to run `vim` with a shell? Why not run `vim file` directly? `std::process::Command::new("vim").arg("file")`…

Comment: @phd yeah, i just realized that about the location of sh, when i ran `which sh` on my machine it said /usr/bin/sh, but on most, including my testing computer, its /bin/sh.
As for the necessity of running in a shell, if you were to run `vim ~/foo` without a shell then it would try to look in the directory ~, not the home directory

Comment: Your `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`, like in many modern Linux distributions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I run your code, `vim` does open in the terminal, but my shell is also running in the same terminal, and both vim and the shell fight for the display and they both receive any key I type. If this is the issue you are seeing too, you need to [wait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait) on the child process:

```
std::process::Command::new("/usr/bin/sh")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("vim")
    .arg("file")
    .spawn()
    .expect("Error: Failed to run editor")
    .wait()
    .expect("Error: Editor returned a non-zero status");
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered it, i had to add `.wait()`, also, it's worth noting that i had to use "vim file" as its own `.arg()`, not separated into 2